# How to check if a user is at a specified latitude/longitude in iOS?

Tags: ios, mapkit

I'm wondering if there is a way to check if a user is actually at a specific location or not (or maybe within 50-100 feet of it). I have a `CLLocationCoordinate2D` defined and I know I can check my `mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude` and `mapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude`, but I'm not sure what the best way to check this would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you just have to compare the lat lon and calculate the distance. Luckily, iOS has a built-in method for that inside the `CLLocation` class.

Here is a simple way to do it.

```
CLLocation* location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:marker.coordinate.latitude longitude:marker.coordinate.longitude];
CLLocationDistance distance = [location distanceFromLocation:userLocation];
```

the returned value is in meters which you can then easily convert to feet or any other unit of measurement that you are interested in.

Here is the documentation for [reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html)